# Unexpected token "." in Exists condition

Tags: msbuild

I have a condition looking for a path that has a "." in the file name, it looks something like this

```
Condition="Exists($(FirstPart).$(SecondPart))"
```

But I get an error saying:

> "." was an unexpected token.

Any tips on how I can do this?

As far as I'm aware, `.` isn't a special character, and it still doesn't work when I try to escape it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might just need to add a `'` on either side of your condition, like:

```
Condition="Exists('$(FirstPart).$(SecondPart)')"
```

That removed the `error MSB4092: An unexpected token "." was found at character position 20 in condition "Exists($(FirstPart).$(SecondPart))"` you were seeing for me.

Here is my test code:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="Exists('$(FirstPart).$(SecondPart)')">
    <Message Text="Hit target." />
  </Target>
```

And output:

```
  1>Target "BeforeBuild" in project "..." (entry point):
    Task "Message"
      Hit target.
    Done executing task "Message".
```

MSDN Reference: [MSBuild Conditions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx)